# Notification for answer that was not accepted

Tags: discussion, feature-request, accepted-answer, notifications

When I answer I usually answer with the intention of providing the best answer in that question. If I can't make that goal I don't even compete. I feel it's a waste of time to add content that is less good than competing content.

That means that I expect to receive the accept check-mark eventually.

I would like to be notified if I answered a question and a different answer was accepted. That way I can learn what my mistake was that lead to me providing an inferior answer. This feature could be a nice self-training facility.

What do you think about that?

Comment: It's not a waste of time to answer questions if your answer's not accepted. Just because OP finds another answer more useful doesn't mean that other people who see it will not find it useful. Not getting accepted doesn't mean something is wrong with your answer, there's nothing to gain by trying to "fix" non-accepted answers. Fix them if they are downvoted, which you *do* get a notification for.

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to have my inbox flooded, so I don't support this feature request :D

Comment: still we can have a check-box to be notified on the case, no?

Comment: Proposals like this start at -100, notifying users about "bad" things cause far too much drama.  Coming up with +101 worth of reasons to add this feature is pretty difficult, you didn't get close.

Comment: @HansPassant that is a very good point.

Answer (score 13):

> When I answer I usually answer with the intention of providing the best answer in that question.

Great!

> That means that I expect to receive the accept check-mark eventually.

Wait, *what*? What if the OP doesn't recognise a good answer even if you smacked him in the face with it?

Write your answers for **every future visitor with the same problem**. It's nice if the OP found your answer great too, but **they are not the only one benefitting**.

Really, accepting is a nice badge (especially when you have hit the rep cap), but in the long run, gain some confidence in your own answers and technical ability. Revisit old answers if and when you notice them (voting activity, comments, etc.), and see what others have said then. Perhaps new answers were posted that are interesting too. Interesting other answers can happen at any time. And take into account that different viewpoints and angles on a problem are always valuable too; your answer may help that future visitor more than the accepted answer you thought so great.

Comment: Well, usually the best answer is accepted in my experience. And in those cases where that isn't the case I'll notice that when revisiting the question.

Comment: I do write my answers for future visitors. But even those users find redundant or inferior answers not valuable. I basically want to learn from cases where I (unwittingly) created an answers that does not need to be there.

Comment: @usr: What if your answer was accepted and it **wasn't** the best answer? I revisit answers regularly, especially if older and they just received a vote. That's a far better habit than to have the system notify me every time a new user tries to accept every answer on a post because they don't yet know how that works. I don't want to be notified that often.

Comment: @usr: And multiple answers that explain a problem in different ways do **not** make them redundant. Different people think in different ways, so explaining something in different ways has enormous value.

Comment: I do care about wrongly received accepts as well. But I do notice those using the regular notifications. Maybe I should simply revisit all answers after a few month like you suggest.